# Unity: How many tmx tiles can I run without lag

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does unity have any limits when it comes to .tmx files? I am creating a .tmx map on tiled and each tile is 16x16 pixels. I am making a game and I would like to make it fairly universal and make sure most graphics cards can handle it but I'm not sure whether I should divide my map in to chunks that will load when the boarder is crossed or just load the whole map, as I'm not sure if I would be able to program the game to only load say a 50x50 texture and render more of the map as the player moves. So does unity have a maximum number of tiles it can render? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open statistics window and see performance stats of your game. Mostly and basicly, [Draw Calls](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) is defined your game's parformance. For example FPS decreases under 60 for more than 2500 draw calls on most of PCs.

Assume that your map is 128x128, if you use 16x16 tiles you need 64 nodes otherwise if you use 32x32 tiles you need 16 nodes. More nodes means more loading.
Just check stats and get visuals under control for better performance.